# Unable to get php variable and later display topics based on the id of the variable

Tags: php

I am building a forum in order to practice and i am having trouble getting a forum ID from the URL and later on the next page i am getting a "Call to undefined function" error. What is is that im doing wrong?

Here is how i pass the forum id from a href, from the main forums page.

```
echo "<a href=forum.php?forum=" . urlencode($array_forums["forum_id"]) . ">";
```

Here is how i get the id inside my topics page, where i should display all topics, related to this forum id.

```
     <?php
        if (isset($_GET['forum'])) {
            $forum_id = $S_GET['forum'];
        }
     ?>

    <div id="topics_container">
        <?php
            //1. Perform database query for topics
            $sql_topic = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_forum_id = {$forum_id}";
            $res_topic = mysqli($conn, $sql_topic);
            //2. Display returned data from topics
            while ($array_topic = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_topic)) {
                echo "<div id='topic_{$array_topic["topic_id"]}'";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: In line 3 you wrote `$S_GET['forum']` instead of `$_GET['forum']` I didn't look further, but maybe that solves it

Comment: Also: Huge security risk in your code (SQL injection) and bad architecture (never mix views with logic. Especially not database logic. Maybe take a look at [MVC](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller)) I realise that this is just for practice, but you should learn how to do it right then

Comment: oops sorry i fixed this and actually found out that instead of mysqli($conn, $sql_topic); it should be mysqli_query($conn, $sql_topic); So its a problem solved.

Comment: @SourceOverflow yea thanks i know, unfortunately i am still a student and will learn more as we get inside the mvc stuff. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found my errors, problem solved.

```
$forum_id = $_GET['forum'];
```

instead of

```
$forum_id = $S_GET['forum'];
```

and

```
mysqli_query($conn, $link)
```

instead of

```
mysqli($conn, $link)
```